# explicit conversion to std::function

Tags: c++, casting, std-function, explicit-conversion

I'm trying to define **explicit conversion** from some class to `std::function` like this:

```
#include <functional>

class ExpInt { private:
    const int value;
public:
    ExpInt(const int v):value(v){}
    explicit operator std::function<int (void)> ()
    {
        return [=](void){ return value; };
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto e = new ExpInt(44);
    auto f = static_cast<std::function<int (void)>>(e);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it I get the following error:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:16:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function<int()>::function(ExpInt*&)’
  auto f = static_cast<std::function<int (void)>>(e);
                                                   ^
```

Comment: Terminology: casting is always explicit; casting is an explicit conversion. There are no implicit casts, only implicit conversions.

Comment: @molbdnilo fixed the phrasing, thanks.

Comment: Please read the error messages! No matching function for call to `std::function<int()>::function(ExpInt*&)`. `ExpInt*&`. Why is that a reference to a pointer? What is `e`?

Comment: Take a closer look at what you're attempting to convert to a `std::function`. It's not what you think it is.

Comment: `auto` is useful, but sometimes is better to write the type down explicitly just to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler tells you what's wrong:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function<int()>::function(ExpInt*&)’
> auto f = static_cast<std::function<int (void)>>(e);
>                                                ^
> ```

A pointer to `ExpInt` is not convertible to `std::function<int (void)>`. `ExpInt` would be convertible, so if you simply indirect through the pointer, that would work:

```
auto f = static_cast<std::function<int (void)>>(*e);
```

P.S. You leak the dynamic allocation. Avoid using owning bare pointers.